# Algebra rules for parenthesis and exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I stumbled upon the following in a textbook, and I can't understand what rules are used/how it converts it.
Part of my problem is that im not quite sure what questions to ask, or how to formulate it.

$$(1,5)^{k-2}+(1,5)^{k-3} $$

Is converted into:

$$(1,5)^{k-1}*((1,5)^{-1}+(1,5)^{-2})$$

Would greatly appreciate it if anyone would take the time to point to the rules used or walk through it step by step.
I have tried looking up rules for exponents and parenthesis but have not been able to find what I was looking for, also tried searching on stackexchange, but I think I might be failing to find the answer due to not searching for the right string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the last expression you have, and distribute: i.e. do $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ with $a=(1.5)^{k-1}$, $b=(1.5)^{-1}$, and $(1.5)^{-2}$.

Then
$$(1.5)^{k-1} \cdot (1.5)^{-1} = (1.5)^{(k-1) + (-1)} = (1.5)^{k-2}$$
and
$$(1.5)^{k-1} \cdot (1.5)^{-2} = (1.5)^{(k-1) + (-2)} = (1.5)^{k-3}$$
and you arrive at the original expression.
These last two steps are due to the rule $x^y \cdot x^z = x^{y+z}$.

Comment: Thx for the rundown, saved my evening, was overcomplicating it a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Rules used:

- $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$
- distributive: $(ad+af)=a(d+f)$

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer!